# sci-fi novel from the 60s 70s or 80s about two civilizations in conflict that are from the same world

Tags: story-identification, novel

It was about two civilizations that were fighting each other, but, unknown to them they shared an origin on the same world. One civilization was obsessed with perfection which to them was pale skin, dark hair, etc. while the other just wanted freedom and love if I remember correctly and they had light hair and tan skin. I think one of the characters had to hide that he wasn't the same as everyone else and use makeup on his skin since it was naturally tan... I also vaguely remember that another character had been raised as an assassin?

It was a paper back. The cover was an illustration that showed one of the pale dark haired men from the perfection race. I know I would know the cover again if I saw it I just can't remember the title of the book.

I read the novel in the 90s and I want to try and find it again to read and buy for my collection.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you read this as a paperback or hard cover?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: It was a paper back. The cover was an illustration that showed one of the pale dark haired men from the perfection race. I know I would know the cover again if I saw it I just can't remember the title of the book.

Comment: Cover supplied; how close is that?

Comment: That is it EXACTLY... Dude! Thank you so much my brain was killing me over this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pale skin with dark hair on one side and tan skin with lighter hair on the other side makes me think of C.S. Friedman's [*In Conquest Born*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1730) (1986).

[image: Cover of "In Conquest Born" showing Zatar on the left and Anzha on the right]

The blurb on the 15th anniversary edition reads:

> Braxi and Azea - two interstellar civilizations fighting an endless war over a long-forgotten cause; two peoples descended from the human species and bred over countless generations to embody opposing ideals, seeking opposite paths to power.
>
> The Braxana - dominant tribe of the fierce Braxin Holding - are brilliant, powerful, and aloof from the society they rule. They were bred by their primitive forebearers to be aggressive, competitive, and secretive beyond all prior human norms. The mysteries of their internal society are legendary even among the people they rule.
>
> The Azeans - masters of genetic science - have redesigned their own race to reflect ancient ideals. Now they seek to unlock the powers of the human mind, using telepathy to penetrate where mere weapons cannot.
>
> But Zatar and Anzha - master Braxana and Azean generals - have exceeded all genetic expectations of their opposed cultures, and have made this endless war a personal vendetta. Who can say what will happen when these ultimate warriors use every power of mind and body to claim the vengeance of total conquest?

Note that some editions were printed with the cover reversed:
[image: Reversed cover of "In Conquest Born" with Anzha on the left and Zatar on the right]